# Export table data into csv file option not there in SQL Developer (Version 3.1.07)

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, export-to-csv

Export table data into csv file option not there in SQL Developer (Version 3.1.07). can anyone please help me to export the one table data into csv file using SQL Developer?

Comment: Upgrade to a more recent SQL Developer version?

Comment: It's there but 3.1 is like 9+ years old

Answer (score 0):

Just need to scroll up to see option for csv file under export in sql developer.